# Google Chrome vs extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to build app that would allow me to open website, select some data from this website and send them to my server. I imagine that it works in this way:

1. Application id displayed in browser sidebar sidebar
2. I open certain website
3. Select address (City) on opened website
4. Click "City" button on sidebar
5. "City" value is copied from website to sidebar
6. Select address (Zip code) in browser
7. Click "Zip code" button on side bar
8. "Zip code" value is copied from website to sidebar
9. ... (and so on)
10. Finally I click "submit" button on sidebar and data is send to server.

What will be better option for such use case? Chrome app or chrome extension? I am not sure if there is  way to display sidebar using chrome extension. I also haven't seen in reference option to open certain url in chrome app. Any advises will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess an extension would be more appropriate as it is just one click away from the website you want to select some data from. The user interaction could be done in various ways:

- select text and use the context menu (right mouse click) to activate the extension logic
- activate extension via toolbar and add UI as a part of the website being viewed or in a separate window

Answer (score 0):

You can pop up a window, but it will disappear when you click back on the website. You can manually create a "sidebar" by having your extension open a new window whose url is inside the extension and subsequently manually placing it alongside the browser window.

Unfortunately there is no sidebar feature for chrome extensions. That would be cool if there were, though.